# How connect multi client to multi server in C#

Tags: c#, sockets

We have 100 devices in tcp server listening to port 5224. I need to connect to these devices and send a byte array to each device and receive a response and show this data. I tried asynchronous socket programming but when I added more than 10 devices it stopped working. Is there any tcp socket limitation? How can I solve this problem (sorry for my English).
this is my client socket class:

```
public class ClientSocket
{
    Socket so;
    IPEndPoint serverEndpoint;      
    public byte[] SendBytes;        
    IPAddress ipaAddress;
    int iPort;        

    public delegate void MessageReceivedEventHandler (object sender,byte[] bytes); 
    public event MessageReceivedEventHandler MessageReceived;       


    public ClientSocket(string ipAddress, string port)
    {
        try
        {
        ipaAddress  = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
        iPort       = int.Parse(port);
        serverEndpoint = new IPEndPoint (ipaAddress , iPort);            

        so = new  Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);            
        so.ExclusiveAddressUse = true;


            IAsyncResult rs = so.BeginConnect(serverEndpoint.Address, serverEndpoint.Port, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), so);
            rs.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(100);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }        
    private void  ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult az)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket sk = (Socket)az.AsyncState;
            sk.EndConnect(az);
            socketObject soo=new socketObject();
            soo.s = sk;

            IAsyncResult rs = sk.BeginReceive(soo.b, 0, soo.b.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), soo);
            rs.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            socketObject oo = (socketObject)ar.AsyncState;                
            int received = oo.s.EndReceive(ar);
            if (received > 0)
            {
                List<byte> ls = new List<byte>();
                ls.AddRange(oo.b.ToList().GetRange(0, received));
                oo.b = new byte[55];
                oo.s.BeginReceive(oo.b, 0, oo.b.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), oo);
                MessageReceived(so, ls.ToArray());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }

    public void SendMessage (byte[] bytes)
    {
        try
        {
            IAsyncResult rs = so.BeginSend(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), so);
            rs.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            so.EndSend(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {               

        }
    }



    class socketObject
    {
        public Socket s;
        public byte[] b=new byte[55];
    }

    public IPAddress SocketIPAddress
    {
        get{return ipaAddress;}
    }
    public int Port
    {
        get { return iPort; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the 10 connection limit on windows client issue?